# Example of a Set with a nonempty interior of a boundary

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to find a example of a metric space X and a subset A which its Int(Bdry(A)) is not empty. I know that Int(Bdry(A)) is empty if A is closed or open, so I tried to find a set which is neither but haven't succeeded to do so.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A= \mathbb{Q}$, then $\partial A = \mathbb{R} = X$,
and so $(\partial A)^\circ \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I haven't thought of that

Answer (score 0):

Try $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{R}$ has the usual Euclidean Topology.

Bdry$(\mathbb{Q})$ = cl$(\mathbb{Q})$\int$(\mathbb{Q})$ = $\mathbb{R}$\ $\emptyset$ = $\mathbb{R}$. Thus the int(bdry($\mathbb{Q}$)) = $\mathbb{R}$